# how to combine these two map conditions

Tags: java, conditional-statements

Is there any way to combine these two conditions in one variable?

```
boolean notNullMappingPresent1 = !isNullOrEmpty(map1) && (isNotNullOrEmpty(map1.get("Value"));
boolean nullMappingPresent1 = (!isNullOrEmpty(map1) && isNullOrEmpty(map1.get("Value")));

boolean notNullMappingPresent2 = !isNullOrEmpty(map2) && (isNotNullOrEmpty(map2.get("Value"));
boolean nullMappingPresent2 = (!isNullOrEmpty(map2) && isNullOrEmpty(map2.get("Value")));


if(notNullMappingPresent1){
    //lines of code
}
if(notNullMappingPresent2){
    //lines of code
}
if(nullMappingPresent1 && nullMappingPresent2){
    //lines of code
}
```

I need to combine `notNullMappingPresent1` and `nullMappingPresent1` also combine `notNullMappingPresent2` and `nullMappingPresent2`. Instead of creating 4 boolean variables can we combine to create 2?

Comment: Can you please describe more, which two condition you want to merge ?

Comment: combine notNullMappingPresent1 and nullMappingPresent1 also combine notNullMappingPresent2 and nullMappingPresent2. Instead of creating 4 boolean variables can we combine to create 2?

Comment: Is the order of the statements within your three `if` conditions relevant?

Comment: Order is not important but these conditions should be checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one option is use a int instead of boolean so that we can have 3 values and can check all the conditions:

```
int mapCode1 = !isNullOrEmpty(map1)?(isNotNullOrEmpty(map1.get("Value1")))?1:0:-1;
int mapCode2 = !isNullOrEmpty(map2)?(isNotNullOrEmpty(map2.get("Value2")))?1:0:-1;


if(mapCode1==0 && mapCode2==0){
        System.out.println("Values of map1 and map2 are null");
    }
if(mapCode1==1){
    System.out.println("Values of map1 are not null");
}
if(mapCode2==1){
    System.out.println("Values of map2 are not null");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that the null check for `map1` and `map2` should be extracted, then the two expressions could be used:

```java
if (!isNullOrEmpty(map1) && !isNullOrEmpty(map2)) {
    boolean nullMapping1 = isNullOrEmpty(map1.get("Value"));
    boolean nullMapping2 = isNullOrEmpty(map2.get("Value"));

    if (nullMapping1 && nullMapping2) {
       // lines of code
    } else {
        if (!nullMapping1) {
            // lines of code
        }
        if (!nullMapping2) {
            // lines of code
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's see this code:

```
boolean notNullMappingPresent1 = !isNullOrEmpty(map1) && (isNotNullOrEmpty(map1.get("Value"));
boolean nullMappingPresent1 = (!isNullOrEmpty(map1) && isNullOrEmpty(map1.get("Value")));
```

`!isNullOrEmpty(map1)` is equivalent to `!isNullOrEmpty(map1)`

`isNotNullOrEmpty(map1.get("Value")` is the exact opposite of `isNullOrEmpty(map1.get("Value"))`

So, in order to simplify this, let's rephrase this in a more sensible manner:

boolean map1NotEmpty = !isNullOrEmpty(map1);
boolean map2NotEmpty = !isNullOrEmpty(map2);
boolean map1Value = isNotNullOrEmpty(map1.get("Value"));
boolean map2Value = isNotNullOrEmpty(map2.get("Value"));

So, your logic would look like this:

```
if (map1NotEmpty || map2NotEmpty) {
    if (map1NotEmpty && map1Value) {
        //...
    } else if (map1NotEmpty && map2Value) {
        //...
    } else if (map1NotEmpty && map2NotEmpty)
}
```

I still use four variables, yes, because there are four things to know:

- is map1 empty?
- is map1 containing value?
- is map2 empty?
- is map2 containing value?

Technically I could combine all this into numeric code, containing a single value, but that would be so hacky that there is no real-life use of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine this two variables like this :

```
if(!isNullOrEmpty(map1) && isNotNullOrEmpty(map1.get("Value")) && isNullOrEmpty(map1.get("Value"))) {
    // Line of code
}

if(!isNullOrEmpty(map2) && isNotNullOrEmpty(map2.get("Value")) && isNullOrEmpty(map2.get("Value"))) {
    // Line of Code
}
```

Note:  Above condition can't match all the time because last two condition functions in first condition is exactly opposite of each other so.

Comment: I cannot combine these 3 checks with && because the if conditions are like said above